# How to avoid multiple images unnecessarily add to a plot

Tags: r, image, animation, plot

I am trying to produce a simple "animation". This is the code that I am using and it works reasonably well:

```
# Use "png" library
library(png)

# Load the images
img1 <- readPNG("filename1.png")
img2 <- readPNG("filename2.png")

# Set up the plot area
plot(10, ann=FALSE, axes=FALSE, asp=1, xlim=c(-1, 1), ylim=c(-1, 1))
# Get the plot information so the image will fill the plot box
lim <- par()

while(TRUE) {
  rasterImage(img1, lim$usr[1], lim$usr[3], lim$usr[2], lim$usr[4])
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
  rasterImage(img2, lim$usr[1], lim$usr[3], lim$usr[2], lim$usr[4])
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
}
```

The problem that I am encountering is that every time `rasterImage` is called a new image is **added** to the plot, and unnecessarily makes it heavier and heavier (if you save the final image after a sufficient number of loops, a very heavy file will be created).

If I call the `plot` function from within the loop, each image is displayed after a long white plot, and the result is useless in addition to being unnerving.

Is there a way around it, i.e. displaying images fast but avoiding they add one over the other?

---

Execution time seems to be the same when `plot` is used inside or outside the loop.

Function `plot` outside the loop

```
# Start the clock
ptm <- proc.time()

# Set up the plot area
plot(10, ann=FALSE, axes=FALSE, asp=1, xlim=c(-1, 1), ylim=c(-1, 1))
# Get the plot information so the image will fill the plot box
lim <- par()

for(i in 1:20) {
  rasterImage(img1, lim$usr[1], lim$usr[3], lim$usr[2], lim$usr[4])
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
  rasterImage(img2, lim$usr[1], lim$usr[3], lim$usr[2], lim$usr[4])
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
}

# Stop the clock
proc.time() - ptm
```

Elapsed time: 26.57 seconds.

Function `plot` inside the loop

```
# Start the clock
ptm <- proc.time()

for(i in 1:20) {
  # Set up the plot area
  plot(10, ann=FALSE, axes=FALSE, asp=1, xlim=c(-1, 1), ylim=c(-1, 1))
  # Get the plot information so the image will fill the plot box
  lim <- par()
  rasterImage(img1, lim$usr[1], lim$usr[3], lim$usr[2], lim$usr[4])
  Sys.sleep(0.1)

  # Set up the plot area
  plot(10, ann=FALSE, axes=FALSE, asp=1, xlim=c(-1, 1), ylim=c(-1, 1))
  # Get the plot information so the image will fill the plot box
  lim <- par()
  rasterImage(img2, lim$usr[1], lim$usr[3], lim$usr[2], lim$usr[4])
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
}

# Stop the clock
proc.time() - ptm
```

Elapsed time: 27.08 seconds.

Comment: strange that plot.new() would slow down your animation, I would have thought rasterImage() would be much slower.

Comment: I have edited my question: actually the big problem is that, if I use 'plot' within the loop, most of the time I just see a white plot. Execution time in the two cases seems to be the same.

Comment: I suspect the real issue is that rasterImage is slow, and it becomes more apparent when you need to wait with a white background, as opposed to a previous image. You could try `grid.newpage(); grid.raster()`, but grid graphics tend to be even slower than base. At least, it would be possible to remove previous grobs, so you could imagine removing older images before saving. It's not clear what device you want to use: animation suggests interactive, but you mention the problem of file size. Can't you export a sequence of images and use e.g. imageMagic to make an animated gif?